# Is there a player's primer for The Wild Beyond The Witchlight?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, the-wild-beyond-the-witchlight

The first paragraph of the introduction of The Wild Beyond the Witchlight states:

> The information in this book is intended for the DM’s eyes only. If you’re planning to play through the adventure with someone else as your DM, stop reading now.

Is there a primer for specific lore/backgrounds to be used in the Wild Beyond the Witchlight that would be useful for players to know for context or for creating a campaign specific character?

Comment: The fact is that there are two races in there (fairy & harengon) which are for players... so I think that statement is not entirely true...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### For basic Feywild lore, start with the information in the *Dungeon Master’s Guide*.

We see in the introduction to *Wild Beyond the Witchlight*:

> Before running this adventure, please read the “Feywild” section in the *Dungeon Master’s Guide*, as it contains useful information about this dusky, fantastic plane of existence.

This section of the DMG contains the setting basics of the Feywild, which should be everything you need to provide to players whose characters would have a basic knowledge of that plane.

Beyond these basic details, it’s up to the DM to determine character specific details to provide. The intro to the adventure has some of this information, and if a character would know more than the basics, you can provide it to them.

There is no *player facing* primer on Feywild lore, because it is up to you, the DM, to determine what information each character would have as you work with the players in character creation.

One of my players made a character whose grandmother had told them stories about the carnival. When they heard the carnival was back, they went to the attic to see if their grandmother’s journals had anything about the carnival. I gave them some basic information about the carnival, and then they found an entry about the Feywild, which I took from the DMG’s flavor text:

> Stepping into the portal was like settling into a warm bath, though the chill didn’t fade from the air. At first everything muted — the roar of the river around the rocks below, the chirping of frogs and crickets on shore, the evening bustle of the town behind him. . . . A moment later, the world erupted into vibrant life. Frogs and night birds sang a chorus; the air was awash with autumn scents; the moonlight painted the flowers in iridescent blue, silver, and violet; and the rushing of the river became a complex symphony.
>
> -James Wyatt, *Oath of Vigilance*

Except of course, it was signed by the grandmother.